# Highlight the duplicate rows in a Excel's workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets with values. The main values are `A` `B` `C` and in the `D` is the result.

When I add a new worksheet and paste the new `ABC` values, I would like to highlignt the duplicate (ie all the A, B and C values are the same) rows if found in another worksheets.

Suppose I have a `Sheet1`

```
A B C D
___________
1 2 3 orange
1 1 2 green
1 1 0 red
4 9 6 orange
2 2 6 orange
```

and I create the `Sheet2` and paste the following

```
A B C D
___________
1 1 2 
X Y Z 
X Y Z  
2 2 6 
1 2 3
```

I would like to transform the `Sheet2` in

```
A B C D
___________
1 1 2 green
X Y Z 
X Y Z 
2 2 6 orange
1 2 3 orange
```

I would like to auto-update the `D` value and, if possible, the background, from the duplicate rows in another sheets, based on the A, B and C values...

Comment: Would matching values between the two sheets always be in the same row of both sheets (as in your example)?

Comment: This does not answer my question at all. In your example `1 1 2` is in row `1` for both sheets. Will this always be the case or could the numbers be on different **rows**?

Comment: updated the OP to clarify that point

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `INDEX/MATCH` in an array formula for this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!A:A=A1)*(Sheet1!B:B=B1)*(Sheet1!C:C=C1),0)),"")
```

Since this is an array formula you must confirm it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: This formula, if I understand well, will check only the `Sheet1` Worksheet... I need that *all* the existing worksheets (but the current one) be checked

Comment: By the way, your solution works great for a *single existing* sheet. Thanks for the idea, I will try to implement it for multiple existing sheets...